# Area under the curve of inverse function.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous and bijective function in $\mathbb{R}$. Let for every t $ t \in \mathbb{R}$, the area bounded by $y= f(x)$, $x=a-t$, $x=a$ and $x$ axis is equal to the area bounded by $y=f(x)$, $x= a+t$, $x=a$ and the $x$ axis.

If $\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}f^{-1}(x)~\mathrm{d}x  = \lambda ka$ (given that $f(a)=0$). Find $k$.

I used the substitution $f^{-1}(x)=t$.

$$\mathrm{d} x = f'(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

$$\int_{f^{-1}(-\lambda)}^{f^{-1}(\lambda)}  tf '(t)~\mathrm{d}t.$$

I thought of using integration by parts. But it is just messed up.

I think we have to use any property of this function but it is not striking to me.

Comment: Use integration by parts on $\int_{f^{-1}(-\lambda)}^{f^{-1}(\lambda)} t df(t)$ differentiating $t$ and integrating $f’(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fact that $f(x)$ has to be antisymmetric with respect to $x=a$ in order to satisfy the conditions above, and the fact that the graph of $f^{-1}(x)$ is the same as that of $f(x)$, but flipped around the $x=y$ line.

You can see that it has to be antisymmetric by thinking about the rate at which the areas from $a-t$ to $a$ and from $a$ to $a+t$ grow as a function of $t$. This rate of change is essentially $|f(a\pm t)|$. Since these two areas are equal at all $t$, their rate of change is also equal, hence $f(a + t) = - f(a - t)$. The sign difference is because the function is bijective.

Given that the integrand is the inverse function, you can consider drawing $f(x)$ and taking the area with respect to the vertical axis, rather than the horizontal one. Then, it is clear that the part from $-\lambda$ to $0$ lacks (or is in excess of) precisely what the part from $0$ to $\lambda$ is in excess of (or lacks).

These two facts together imply that $k=2$. In the figure, the blue area is equal to the dashed area. The blue and green areas add up to the same as the red one. Therefore, the integral you ask about is twice the area of the red rectangle, hence, $2\lambda a$.
[image]

As a last remark, the more analytical approach suggested in the comments of integration by parts yields the same result, once you take into account the symmetry properties of $f(x)$.